# Simple SQL UPDATE Not Working MS Access 2016

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table named Inventory. I have a second table named Sales. As a sale is made, I want to change the status of the item in the Inventory item to "Sold." This SQL query doesn't work and is tied to a button on a Sales form:

```
UPDATE Inventory 
INNER JOIN Sales ON Inventory.[Vehicle ID] = Sales.[VehicleID] 
SET Inventory.[Vehicle Status] = "SOLD" 
WHERE Inventory.[Vehicle ID] = Sales.[VehicleID]
```

Comment: You can not use inner join as target in an Update statement

Comment: it is always better to include the full error message rather thana blunt "does not work"

Comment: What if you took your car to the garage and told them "My car doesn't work." ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct format for MS ACCESS is

```
UPDATE Inventory 
INNER JOIN Sales ON Inventory.[Vehicle ID] = Sales.[VehicleID] 
SET Inventory.[Vehicle Status] = "SOLD";
```

The correct SQL format is:

```
UPDATE Inventory 
SET [Vehicle Status] = "SOLD" 
FROM Inventory
INNER JOIN Sales ON Inventory.[Vehicle ID] = Sales.[VehicleID]
```

if these sql statement doesn't work then it is possible that `vehicle Id` are not same or missing from a table